# Console application freeze without debugging mode

Tags: c#, freeze, usb-flash-drive

I have got simple c# console application, which copies files from flash disk to another flash disk. If I run this app in Visual studio, everything is ok, but if i want to run it through .exe file, app doesnt start and nothing happend. I have tried Debug mode, Release mode and change framework to lower one.

Ther is source code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Helper hlp = new Helper();
        for (int i = 0; i < hlp.GetDevices().Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(hlp.GetDevices()[i]);
        }

        if (hlp.GetDevices().Count.Equals(2))
        {
            if (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Equals(hlp.GetDevices()[0]))
            {
                hlp.DirectoryCopy(hlp.GetDevices()[1].ToString(), ".", true);
            }
            else
            {
                hlp.DirectoryCopy(hlp.GetDevices()[0].ToString(), ".", true);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Operace dokoncena.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vlozte do PC 2 flashdisky.");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and Helper.cs:

```
class Helper
{
    public List<string> GetDevices()
    {
        List<string> devices = new List<string>();
        var driveList = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo drive in driveList)
        {
            if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            {
                devices.Add(drive.Name);
            }
        }
        return devices;
    }

    public void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Zdrojovy adresar neexistuje!" + sourceDirName);
            }

            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }

            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
                File.SetAttributes(file.DirectoryName, FileAttributes.Normal);
                file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
            }

            if (copySubDirs)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                    DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: This exception-eating empty `catch` looks suspicious.

Comment: Not exactly a response, but why create a console app doing a thing you can do with an OS command?

Comment: @FelicePollano obviously he / she is just starting out learning programming. All of us went on that stage.

Comment: We've had a lot of these kind of questions in the past week.  Uninstall Avast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried turn off the Windows Smart screen and app starts working :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to Run it in Admin mode?

And one Improvment of your Programm store the list of the Device than it is faster ;-)

```
List<string> deviceList = hlp.GetDevices();
```

And then your Programm is faster when a lot of devices is connected.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried without any flash drive? Just to get "Vlozte do PC 2 flashdisky." message. Because your code was working normally for me in visual studio 2015 with .NET framework 4.5.2